# Symfony Lock Component does not lock – how to fix?

Tags: php, symfony, locking, symfony-3.4

i upgraded recently to Symfony 3.4.x, refactor LockHandler because of deprecation warning and fall into strange behaviour.

Code in command before refactoring:

```php
class FooCommand
{
    protected function configure() { /* ... does not matter ... */ }
    protected function lock() : bool
    {
        $resource = $this->getName();
        $lock     = new \Symfony\Component\Filesystem\LockHandler($resource);

        return $lock->lock();
    }
    protected function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->lock()) return 0;

        // Execute some task
    }
}
```

And it prevents to run two command at the same time – second just finishes without doing job. That is good.

But after suggested refactoring it allows to run many commands simultaneously. This is FAIL. How to prevent execution? New code:

```php
class FooCommand
{
    protected function configure() { /* ... does not matter ... */ }
    protected function lock() : bool
    {
        $resource = $this->getName();
        $store    = new \Symfony\Component\Lock\FlockStore(sys_get_temp_dir());
        $factory  = new \Symfony\Component\Lock\Factory($store);
        $lock     = $factory->createLock($resource);

        return $lock->acquire();
    }
    protected function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->lock()) return 0;

        // Execute some task
    }
}
```

NB #1: I don't care about many servers or so, just one instance of application.

NB #2: If process was killed then new command must unlock and run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use the LockableTrait trait

```
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\LockableTrait;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command

    class FooCommand  extends Command
    {
        use LockableTrait;
.....
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if (!$this->lock()) {
            $output->writeln('The command is already running in another process.');

            return 0;
        }
// If you prefer to wait until the lock is released, use this:
        // $this->lock(null, true);

        // ...

        // if not released explicitly, Symfony releases the lock
        // automatically when the execution of the command ends
        $this->release();

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works good. Sad that documentation does not contain this.

Comment: It should be noted that the `LockableTrait` is really just a helper for Symfony Console commands. It only implements two locking stores, and they're both local. They are the `FlockStore` and `SemaphoreStore` stores. This will not work with `MemcachedStore` or `RedisStore`. If either of those latter stores are required, then the `LockableTrait` is not going to help.

Comment: Thank you for noticing this! I saw source of trait – it's really simple. For my purposes, local storage enough.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Mohamed answer, it's important to assign an id to the command locker.

Otherwise the lock will have concurrency problems with other commands, specially if you have different environments (test, production, stage...). You'll see that the command is not being executed with the expected periodicity.

This id can be assigned on the `lock()` statement itself.

```
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\LockableTrait;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command

    class FooCommand  extends Command
    {
       use LockableTrait;
       .....
       protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
       {
         if (!$this->lock('FooCommand'.getenv('APP_ENV'))) {
            $output->writeln('The command is already running in another process.');
            return 0;
         }

         $this->release();
       }
    }
```